# JavaScript function not working unless it has setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, alert

```
function sayHello(name)
    {
        var prompt = "Hello, " + name + "!";
        function asd()
        {
            alert(prompt);
        }
    }
```

This code is not working. I have an HTML file with a button, that has an `onClick='sayHello("MyName")'`. It doesn't work, unless I add a `setTimeout(asd, 0);` after the inner function. Any idea why (or what I'm doing wrong)? I'm just starting JS and this is very strange to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to invoke your *function*.

```
function sayHello(name) {
    var prompt = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    function asd() {
        alert(prompt);
    }
    asd(); // invoke
}
```

Comment: @nnnnnn true. I feel this code is unlikely to be OPs ultimate goal, so I kept it

Comment: Thank you, hadn't thought about that. Works fine now :) Also I know I could have gotten rid of it, but I was testing the scopes, cause they aren't like in other programming languages. Thanks again!